# Get financial year by given month

Tags: php

Financial year starts on 01 April and we are in January so January falls into year 2020 and so is February and March. So if I use April now, it should fall in to year 2019. Currently I used the following code but it doesn't work the way I want it

```
    $month =01;
   if ( $month >= 4 ) {
     $year = date('Y');
   }
   else {
    $year = date('Y')-1;
   }
   echo $year;
```

SO when I set the month to 1 which is January, the year shows as 2019 but it should really be 2020.

Is there anyway to set the year in PHP so when the months will start from April and ends end of March so when I enter a month, I will get the correct year?

Comment: You said _So if I use April now, it should fall in to year 2019_. So this means Financial year 2019 ends on April 1st. Yes?

Comment: Yes true. Every year financial year will start 1st of April.

Comment: You also said _SO when i set the month to 1 which is January, the year shows as 2019 but it should really be 2020_ How come? The financial year still going to complete on April 1st. So why would January show as 2020?

Comment: Your code is correct, but your explanation is not and contradicting with what you want to achieve. What should be the output for Jan, Feb, Mar and finally April in terms of year?

Comment: Because if I am suppose to pull data from mysql like income or an expense, it should be year 2020. also I think i found to answer. please check the answer i will post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i managed to fix the issue. Any comments is welcomed

```
$month =01;
$current_month = date('m');
if ($current_month >= '01' && $current_month < '4'){

   if ($month >= '01' && $month < '04'){
      $year = date('Y');
   } 

   if ($month >= 4){
      $year = date('Y')-1;
   }
} 

if ($current_month >= 4){
   if ($month >= 4){
      $year = date('Y');
   }

   if ($month < 4){
      $year = date('Y')+1;
   }
}

echo $year;
```

Comment: So for `May` month it will be 2019?

Comment: check this out @vivek_23

Comment: I suggest you use (int) '04'  (int) $month etc to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: `Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->year`

This way January, February, and March dates will return 2019, and April will start returning 2020 as year.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your issue

```
$date=date_create("2020-05-13");

echo "<br> Month: ".date_format($date,"m");
if (date_format($date,"m") >= 4) {//On or After April (FY is current year - next year)
    $financial_year = (date_format($date,"Y")) . '-' . (date_format($date,"y")+1);
} else {//On or Before March (FY is previous year - current year)
    $financial_year = (date_format($date,"Y")-1) . '-' . date_format($date,"y");
}

echo "<br> FY ".$financial_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines :

```
$now = strtotime('now');
$firstApril = strtotime('1st april');
$year = ($now < $firstApril) ? date('Y')-1 : $date('Y');
return $year;
```

This would compare the timestamp and if its less than 1st april of this year than it will get the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 $month =01;
 if($month>=4&&$month<=12){
     $year=date('Y')-1;
 }
 if($month>=1&&$month<=3){
     $year=date('Y');
 }
   echo $year;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer, but if you handle multiple financial/transactional data for a financial year for your business, you probably are in a similar position as I was a few years back.

Feel free to check this library -> https://github.com/RoussKS/financial-year

It would be an overkill for a single checking (even though considerably lightweight), but if you have more requirements, it could be useful.

Requires the start of the financial year date and the type of the financial year (in your case, it's `calendar` as per library's spec) and provides ending date, period ranges and more.

Returns a DateTimeImmutable object or a DatePeriod depending the method used (get a date, period, or week for `business` type financial year only)

In your case, the use case would be like

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// DateTimeAdapter
// If instantiating with string, it must be of ISO-8601 format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
$startDate = new \DateTime('2019-04-01');

$fy = new \RoussKS\FinancialYear\DateTimeAdapter('calendar', $startDate);

// January is the 10th period for a financial year based on 12 periods starting at 2019-04-01.
// First date of the period would give you  2020-01-01
echo $fy->getFirstDateOfPeriodById(10)->format('Y'); // 2020
```

Feel free to test and advise

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the start date for the current financial year (start date 1st April).

```
public function getFinancialYear(){

    $today = Carbon::today();
    $month = $today->format('m');
    $year = $today->format('Y');

    $firstApril = 'first day of April '.$year;

    $financialYear = new Carbon($firstApril);

    if($month < 4){
        $financialYear->subYear();
    }

    return $financialYear;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fascal_year(){
 $today_year = date("Y");
 $today_month = date("m");
 $fascal_year = "";
 if($today_month <= 6){
    $fascal_year = ($today_year - 1) ."-". $today_year;
 }else{
    $fascal_year = $today_year."-".($today_year + 1);
 }
 return $fascal_year;
}
```